# Flutter runJavascriptReturningResult returns "{}"

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a JavaScript function that returns some data. When I run this function directly from the browser I get the expected result. However, when I run it from the Flutter WebView using runJavascriptReturningResult(), I always get a string like '{}'.

The JavaScript function makes an axios call, but I'm not sure if this is relevant.

I'm already running runJavascriptReturningResult() only when the onPageFinished event is fired, as recommended.

```
      var controller = await _controllerCompleter.future;
      var result = await controller.runJavascriptReturningResult('getSomeData()');
```

Also, I am using a React/Next application within the WebView. I don't think this should be a problem since I already have access to the DOM when calling the function from Flutter. And if I call an nonexistent function I recieve "null" as response and not "{}". However, I'm not sure if this information is relevant. For reference, here's the part of the code where I expose the JavaScript function to be called from the WebView:

```
  const getSomeData = useCallback( async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/getData', {
      })
      return JSON.stringify(response)
    } catch (e) {
      return JSON.stringify(e)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    (window as any).getSomeData = getSomeData
  }, [])
```

I also already tried to put an "await" before the js function at the flutter call since the function is async, but when doing this the result becomes "null":

```
var result = await controller.runJavascriptReturningResult('await getSomeData()');
```

Another thing that I tried is to return the full response instead of the JSON.stringfy(response). Got the same result.

By the way I added a console.log(response) before the JS return and it is returning the correct data. The problem is just that when the flutter app reads the data it becomes "{}"